# Derivative of $e^x$ (ii)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

This may be quite basic. I'm trying to understand the idea that $\frac{d(e^x)}{dx}=e^x$. Could someone please explain to me what's wrong with the following argument?

$e$ can be defined as the positive number such that

$$\frac{d(e^x)}{dx}=e^x\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

Suppose we apply differential triangles with unit bases, like the ones pictured below.

Since $dx=1$,

$$\frac{d(e^x)}{dx}=d(e^x)\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

so from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have

$$d(e^x)=e^x\;\;\;\;\;(3)$$

Now, by considering the verticals of the triangles it seems to me that

$$d(e^x)=e^{x_{n+1}}-e^{x_n}\;\;\;\;\;(4)$$

so from $(3)$ and $(4)$ we have

$$e^x=e^{x_{n+1}}-e^{x_n}\;\;\;\;\;(5)$$

Evaluating at $n=1$,

$$e^x=e^{x_2}-e^{x_1}\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=e^2-e^1\;\;\;\;\;(6)$$

but evaluating at $n=2$,

$$e^x=e^{x_3}-e^{x_2}\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=e^3-e^2\;\;\;\;\;(7)$$

so something seems to be wrong.

[image]

Comment: It is not true that $dx=1.$ You're confusing derivatives with differentials.

Comment: $dx$ is infinitesimal so it can't be $1$. At best, you can say $\Delta(e^x)\approx\Delta x\cdot e^x$

Comment: @AdrianKeister By $dx$ I mean the base of the differential triangle, which could be made infinitessimal, and I'm trying to understand how the two ideas (finite base and infinitessimal base) fit together.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Above comment also for you.

Comment: Recall that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. So the equation $d(e^x)=dx\cdot e^x$ is only true under the assumption $dx\to0$. You can, however, say that $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}\approx\frac{dy}{dx}$ with the approximation by $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ getting better and closer to $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $\Delta x$ tends to zero.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri This notational distinction is new to me. Is Δ used to represent finite differences? Leibniz's manuscripts have $d$ for both finite and infinitessimal differences.

Comment: Yes, atleast in my place, $\Delta$ is used for finite differences and $d$ for infinitesimals.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri OK, that's useful to know. But shouldn't the *ratio* remain the same regardless of the scale?

Comment: In general this ratio will depend on the value of $x$ and $\Delta x$, since$$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)}{\Delta x}$$If you fix $x$, then the ratio depends on $\Delta x$ alone, so scale matters.

Comment: Ratios are scale-invariant means that the value of the ratio doesn't change if the numerator and denominator are multiplied by the same non-zero constant. Since $\Delta y=y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)$ is an arbitrary, possibly non-linear, function of $x$ and $\Delta x$, it may not scale by the same amount as $\Delta x$. As for why $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equals $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ only at the limit, the answer is it is how derivative is defined. Taking $\Delta x\to0$ rids the ratio of its dependency on $\Delta x$ so that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ depends only on $x$.

Comment: Basically you have a difference quotient with $\Delta x=1$: $\frac{\Delta e^{x\cdot n}}{\Delta  x}=\frac{f(n\cdot (x+1))-f(n\cdot x)}{x+1-x}=f(n\cdot (x+1))-f(n\cdot x)$

But you need the differential quotient to obtain the derivative: That means that $\Delta x\to 0$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks, I think I will take some time to chew that over. I deleted my previous comment as, on re-reading yours, I thought it was redundant, but I'm glad you replied to it anyway.

Comment: The problem is that one the one hand, you are considering the real change in height of the actual function, but on the other, differentials are for the change in height of the tangent line. The biggest problem is step 4. On the left hand side you have the change in height of a specific tangent line, on the right, the change in height of the actual function

Comment: @DWade64 I don't really follow. $y=e^x$, so $d(e^x)=d(y)$, which is the change in height of the function, not of the tangent. No?

Comment: The triangles in your pictures have heights that start and stop on the function. That's the right hand side of step 4. However differentials tell you the change in height of the tangent lines (not shown in your picture). For an increment of 1, the function does increase by some amount. But for an increment of 1, each instantaneous tangent line also increases by some amount (a little bit less than the function because all the tangent lines are below the function)

Comment: By the way, many of these comments are pretending that there is no such thing as a "differential" which is fine. But differentials are just as well defined as derivatives. They are used extensively in differential equations, and have great value (again, you could just use derivatives and never touch differentials in a course on differential equations..but they really do have great value and they are well defined)

Comment: So these trianges you are showing aren't the differential triangles you are looking for. This is what a differential triangle looks like (just some random website that I didn't read though, I just looked at the picture) https://www.geogebra.org/m/FH3yPDCh It shows for an increment of $1$, the tangent height rises by $1.88$

Comment: You could define $d$ to be the change in height of the function. But I wouldn't because most people use $d$ as the way it's defined (see answer). For the change in height of the function, I would use $\Delta y$ or $\Delta f$. $\Delta$'s are used for changes. $d$'s are used for derivative/differential/tangent line stuff

Comment: @DWade64 I'm going to have to reply a bit piecemeal as I'm still digesting. I think the triangles I used can naturally be called differential triangles as their slope is the average slope of the function over the $x$ interval and I think they're in the spirit of Barrow's original (http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Diagrams/Barrow's_triangle.jpeg). I think I can adopt the Δ notation for finite differences without much problem. By "change in height of the tangent lines" do you mean the change in *length* of the tangent lines? If not it sounds like you're talking about the $y$ value.

Comment: By "change in height of a tangent line", I mean the "y-direction", or "vertical change" of a tangent line (for a given horizontal increment) as you guessed. A tangent line is attached to a specific point on the function. From that point, walk out a length (horizontally) some distance. In this question, we took increments of 1. But we could have walked out 2 or 3 units or whatever distance we want. The change in height of the function would be, after we walked, how far we would have to go up or down to get back to the function. The change in height of the tangent line would be,after we walked,

Comment: how far up or down we would have to go to get back to the tangent line

Comment: @DWade64 So given that the tangent line in only of interest where it intersects the curve, what difference, if any, is there between this usage of "change in height of a tangent line" and "change in height of a function"?

Comment: In my link, after walking a distance of 1, you walk up a distance of 1.88 to get to the tangent line. So we rose in height by 1.88 to get back to the tangent line. We changed height by 1.88. But in that same link, after walking horizontally a distance of 1, we would have to keep going further to get back to the function. We would have to rise in height greater than 1.88 to get back to the function. The change in height of the function would be larger. A tangent line can intersect a curve 0 times or as many times as it wants (depending on the curve). It's not about where the two intersect

Comment: Your picture doesn't show any tangent lines. They are secant lines. Tangent lines aren't average slopes, they are instantaneous slopes

Comment: @DWade64 Yes, tangent lines aren't average slopes, but I think the slope of a differential triangle is, and the average becomes instantaneous at the limit. I get the height-of-tangent vs height-of-function distinction you're making. I think I'll go away and digest now, so thanks for the conversation.

Comment: You're welcome! I've never heard of a differential triangle before but I see now how you're using it. Your biggest mistake is actually step 3 then. Step 1 is a full limit. It's the derivative. Step 2 would be the limit of the differential triangle at just one step (it's not the entire limit). So going to step 3, you equate a limit (keep getting smaller and smaller forever) to something that's not a limit, but just a single triangle. So my new answer now would be to use $\frac{d}{dx}$ in the proper way. $\frac{d}{dx}$ always indicates a limiting procedure. For me, I never break off the

Comment: denominator $dx$ from the full symbol $\frac{d}{dx}$. It's one single operator. I was getting confused with seeing single $d$'s everywhere. That's why I left my answer about the differential. So forget that answer, just know what $\frac{d}{dx}$ always indicates a derivative (the full limit definition). I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It follows from
the functional equation for
$f(x) = e^x$:
$f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$
and the assumption that
$f(x)$
is differentiable at $x=0$.

Putting $y=0$,
$f(x) = f(x)f(0)$
so,
if $f$ is not zero at some $x$,
$f(0) = 1$.

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)f(h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}f(x)\dfrac{f(h)-1}{h}\\
&=f(x)\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(h)-1}{h}\\
&=f(x)\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\\
&=f(x)f'(0)\\
\end{array}
$

So any differentiable solution to
$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
satisfies
$f'(x) = f(x)f'(0)$
and $e^x$
is the particular one for which
$f'(0) = 1$.

Note that all differentiable solutions to
$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
are of the form
$f(x) = a^x$
so that
$f'(x) = \ln(a)a^x
=\ln(a)f(x)
$
so that
$f'(0) = \ln(a)
$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative operator is $\frac{d}{dx}$ and I write the derivative of a function as $\frac{d}{dx}f$ for clarity (notice that I keep $\frac{d}{dx}$ together as 1 object with $f$ off to the side).

The [differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Definition) is $d$ and the differential of a function $f$ is written $df$. The definition is $df := \frac{d}{dx}f \; \Delta x$. For a given function $f$, notice how $\frac{d}{dx}f$ itself is a function of $x$. For a given function $f$, notice how $df$ is itself a function of $x$ (from the $\frac{d}{dx}f$ part) and $\Delta x$. So if you give me an $x$ value, and an increment value $\Delta x$, then I can plug those numbers into $df (x, \Delta x)$ to get the value of the change in height *of the tangent line*. $\frac{d}{dx}f$ gives the slope, but $df$ gives the change in height of a tangent line.

[Given an independent variable, the increment $\Delta x$ is usually written as $dx$. If you wanted to be really rigorous in your thinking however, then you would remember that you can only take differentials (or derivatives) of functions. So the $x$ here in $dx$ is actually a function. Let me explain. Consider $f: x \mapsto e^x$. You can either write $df$ or $d(e^x)$. Now consider the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) $g: x\mapsto x$. The differential would be written $dg$ or $d(x)$ where the $x$ in $d(x)$ is that 2nd $x$ after the mapsto arrow $\mapsto$...just as $e^x$ is the thing following the mapsto arrow in $x \mapsto e^x$. Okay so we know what $dx$ now means. But why can we equate $\Delta x$ with $dx$? We just follow the defintion. The derivative of the identity function is $1$ so $d(x) = 1 \Delta x$ or just $d(x) = \Delta x$ or just $dx = \Delta x$]

In your question, following the definition of a differential, we jump straight to step $3$, $d(e^x) = \frac{d}{dx}e^x \Delta x$. Let our increment be $1$, so $d(e^x) = e^x$

At $x = 0$, the $x = 0$ tangent line rises by $d(e^x)|_{x=0, \Delta x = 1} = e^0$

At $x = 1$, the $x = 1$ tangent line rises by $d(e^x)|_{x=1, \Delta x = 1} = e^1$

At $x = 2$, the $x = 2$ tangent line rises by $d(e^x)|_{x=2, \Delta x = 1} = e^2$